# Show my socket.on event in angular using socket.io-cliente

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket

Im using socket.io-client with Angular and I try to show my server request with

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    socket.on('cargarGrupos', resp => {
    this.Grupos = resp;
    });
  }
```

but when i make an *ngFor it doesn't work, how can I solve this problem, I would like to have a service just for the sockets events but They only show them in console